# What is the difference between は and を?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-を

They seem to be used in the same way.

Comment: In the same way... はを so? Do you have some example sentences you've been thinking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well は is used a lot as a topic particle and を (o) is used as a direct object marker..

Direct Object Marker:

eg:

ほんをください。
    *Give me the book please.*

おなまえはなんですか。
*What's your name?*

Here is some more background on は　を　＆　へ:

[Why are the particles "は" (ha⇒wa), "へ" (he⇒e), and "を" (wo⇒o) not spelled phonetically?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/379/why-are-the-particles-%E3%81%AF-ha%E2%87%92wa-%E3%81%B8-he%E2%87%92e-and-%E3%82%92-wo%E2%87%92o-not-spelled-phonet)

Comment: In the second sentence, you forgot an えin おなまえ.

Comment: But more importantly, in some places は does replace を.

Comment: @virmaior Yes!  And less importantly, there's the archaic/literary [をば](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/239144/m0u/%E3%82%92%E3%81%B0/), which is from を＋は.

Comment: Thank you bruno.. should never try to type whilst tired! :)